# String between two markers using PyParsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, text-parsing, pyparsing

I need to obtain a string between two markers using PyParsing.

From the string `s = 'qwertyAAA1234ZZZazerty'` I want to retrieve the string between `AAA` and `ZZZ` which is `1234`.

So far I'm able to do it using `searchString()`. Is it possible to obtain the same result with `parseString()`?

**Using PyParsing's searchString()**

```py
import pyparsing as pp

word = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)

s = 'qwertyAAA1234ZZZazerty'
rule = pp.nestedExpr('AAA', 'ZZZ')
for match in rule.searchString(s):
    print(match)
```

which yields:

`[['1234']]`

**Using PyParsing's parseString()**

```py
import pyparsing as pp

word = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)

s = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'
rule = pp.nestedExpr('AAA', 'ZZZ')
print(rule.parseString(s))
```

which yields:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(rule.parseString(s))
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1939, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1929, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse(instring, 0)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1669, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 4430, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1669, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 4430, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1669, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 4020, in parseImpl
    loc, resultlist = self.exprs[0]._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1673, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 4430, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1673, in _parseNoCache
    loc, tokens = self.parseImpl(instring, preloc, doActions)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2871, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "AAA", found 'g'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try SkipTo, or its shortcut `...`:

```
print((... + rule).parseString(s).dump())
```

Gives:

```
['gfgfd', ['1234']]
- _skipped: ['gfgfd']
```